# Problems with WordPress Multisite and different siteurl and home url

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I'm trying to get a WordPress installation working with the following parameters:

1) The installation and admin are on multi.petersons.com
2) Multisite is using subfolders (not subdomains)
3) Each site points to www.petersons.com/sitename

The admin works fully at multi.petersons.com/wp-admin and multi.petersons.com/sitename/wp-admin. When I create a new post in a multisite, the permalink preview on the post page is correct, e.g. www.petersons.com/sitename/postname. However, when I preview a post in a multisite, it redirects back to multi.petersons.com. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks!

My Web.config code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:3}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My wp-config code is:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'multi.petersons.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/' );
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');
```

Here is my wp_options table for the main site:
[image]

Here is my wp_blogs table:
[image]

Here is my wp_options table for one of the multisites:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try disable plugins and activate one by one.

Moreover this way you can see culprit. Once culprit you discover just look at offending code.

When looked offending code search on preferred search engine and see what search result give you. Base on result there you have propose fix.

May try look for sumer plugin for make it easier.

Comment: Thanks. I've disabled all plugins to no avail.